# SoundLoader overlaps songs in kivy, python. How to play a song in place of other in python kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, android-music-player

> I have been developing an app using python and kivymd 
> This is a simple music player app which finds all the music in the phone and show it as a list
> And when we click on the song name it will play the song
> But the problem is that the songs overlaps and then it keep on overlapping 
> What I want is that when we click on any other song the previous one stops and the clicked one starts to play
> **My previous code in which there is no stop function-:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
import os

helper_string = """
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: scroll

"""


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/'):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                    required_file = file
                    the_location = os.path.abspath(required_file)
                    self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=required_file, on_release=self.play_song))
                    # print(required_file)

    def play_song(self, onelinelistitem):
        # print('play:', onelinelistitem.text)
        the_song_path = os.path.abspath(onelinelistitem.text)
        sound = SoundLoader.load(the_song_path)
        if sound:
            sound.play()
        print(the_song_path)


MainApp().run()
```

> **My new code in which I tried a simple fix using the lists and it also did not worked -:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
import os

helper_string = """
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: scroll

"""


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/'):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                    required_file = file
                    the_location = os.path.abspath(required_file)
                    self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=required_file, on_release=self.play_song))
                    # print(required_file)

    def play_song(self, onelinelistitem):
        SongList = []
        # print('play:', onelinelistitem.text)
        the_song_path = onelinelistitem.secondary_text
        SongList.append(the_song_path)
        if len(SongList) == 1:
            sound = SoundLoader.load(SongList[0])
            if sound:
                sound.play()
            print(the_song_path)
        if len(SongList) > 1:
            SoundLoader.load(SongList[0]).stop()
            sound = SoundLoader.load(SongList[1])
            if sound:
                sound.play()
            print(the_song_path)


MainApp().run()
```

> Yes I know that it was a very bad fix
> ***So please can anyone help me out with this issue 
>
> Thank you Very Much in advance***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SongList` is a local variable in method `play_song()` and is set to `[]` every time `play_song()` is called. So the condition:

```
if len(SongList) > 1:
```

will never be true. An easy way to handle this is to define an instance variable that holds the currently playing sound, lets call it it `self.sound`. Initialize it in the `build()` method:

```
def build(self):
    self.sound = None
    screen = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
    return screen
```

And use it in the `play_song()` method:

```
def play_song(self, onelinelistitem):
    the_song_path = onelinelistitem.secondary_text
    if self.sound:
        self.sound.stop()
    self.sound = SoundLoader.load(the_song_path)
    if self.sound:
        self.sound.play()
    print(the_song_path)
```